# Drupal installation: Set xdebug.max_nesting_level=256 in your PHP configuration

Tags: php, drupal, installation, drupal-8

I am following a tutorial here 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5i6emqdOgg

In between the installation I get this page, where it shows that there are some requirements missing. One of them says `Set xdebug.max_nesting_level=256 in your PHP configuration`

I went to `C:\wamp\www\sampleWebSite\sites\default` which has :

1. files
2. default.services.yml
3. default.settings.php
4. settings.php

I opened `settings.php` to see `xdebug` settings but it was missing there. So I added a line there `xdebug.max_nesting_level=256` and then refreshed the page and page gave me error, so I went to same `settings.php` file again and changed it `$settings['xdebug.max_nesting_level'] = 256;` there is no error now but page still shows that `xdebug` setting is not set to 256.

How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add this line `xdebug.max_nesting_level = 256` in correct `php.ini` file instead of `settings.php`

To it correctly follow below steps:

1. Open notepad or any text editor and save it as `phpinfo.php` with content

   ```
   <?
   php phpinfo();
   ?>
   ```
2. Put this file in directory which you renamed in the given youtube tutorial i.e. `drupal` installation directory
3. Start your wampserver and goto this directory using any browser. Info like this would appear.[image]
4. You now have the correct `php.ini` in which you need to make the xdebug changes
5. Find the `xdebug` and at the end add this line.Like this [image]
6. Save the file and restart wamp server.

[image]

7. Now go to the Requirements problems page and you won't see this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you usually do this either in **php.ini** or better in folder with php folder extensions configurations files there should be file **xdebug.ini**:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 256
```

You can find location of php.ini file in wamp manager or using phpinfo() function in any php file.

After adding values there, you must restart your server.

Comment: I added above line at the end of `php.ini` at this location `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini` but no change error is still there.

Comment: did you restart the server? is it the correct php.ini that is actually being used?

Comment: also please, upgrade your php/wamp - we already have php 7 but you should use at least 5.6

Comment: if you confirm the php.ini is correct and server restarted, one more thing which seems possible that this setting could be overwritten somewhere -> then you should use text search to find where

Comment: this php came with latest wamp from wampserver.com. And Yes, I started the server after editing php.ini. I am not sure this is the correct php.ini I am new to drupal.

Comment: did you try to use phpinfo() to locate php.ini or here /admin/reports/status/php - to locate the correct php.ini

Comment: Thank You i have put the code in .htaccess file of the drupal site and it works